# find and print webpage size in bytes and count of all <a> tags

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, jsdom

I'm working on a CLI tool that takes URL arguments as input. I'm using [jsdom package](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) to create a pseudo-DOM inside node.js to work out with the problem. I'm using the following vanilla-js script:

```js
console.log('Page Size (in bytes): ', (document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].outerHTML.length) / 1024);
console.log('Count of <a> tags: ', document.getElementsByTagName('a').length);
```

```html
<a href="">
<a href="">
<a href="">
<a href="">
<a href="">
```

as following inside my node.js environment:

```
'use strict';

const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

// run loop for first argument till last
process.argv.slice(2, process.argv.length).forEach(function () {

// getting the url as argument
var pgurl = "" + process.argv[2];
console.log('For ', pgurl);

const document = (new JSDOM(``, {
    url: pgurl,
    pretendToBeVisual: true
})).window.document;

console.log('Page Size (in bytes): ', (document.getElementsByTagName('HTML')[0].outerHTML.length) / 1024);
console.log('Count of <a> tags: ', document.getElementsByTagName('a').length);
```

});

Now, since the initial in-browser solution worked for me I tried implementing on node.js and for https://facebook.com passed as an argument, it displays the following output:

```
For  https://facebook.com
Page Size (in bytes):  0.0380859375
Count of <a> tags:  0
```

which remains same across all inputs, regardless of the content.

Is there any other solution to this as basically what I want is to implement browser DOM inside node.js while I pass my URLs are input argument to be processed as shown in the snippet above.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems going on.

The most trivial is that you are calculating a "Page Size **(in bytes)**" (emphasis added) but dividing the string length by 1024 which is what you'd do to count kilobytes. Note that string length is equal to byte length only in a limited number of cases.

A bigger issue is that you do not define what you mean by "page size". For instance, people often talk of "page size" as the size of the initial payload that the server sends to the browser. Using `outerHTML` is not reliable for that, because the payload was probably compressed. If what you want is the size of the HTML *that was given to the browser to make the page*, `outerHTML` is still not reliable because it shows you the *cleaned up* HTML rather that the *original HTML* that the browser received.

Yet another issue is that sites like Facebook construct their page using JavaScript so the JavaScript code has to run first. JSDOM by default does not execute JavaScript. The reason for this is that it is not possible for JSDOM to guarantee that JavaScript executing on a page processed by JSDOM won't be able to do malicious actions. See [this explanation](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#executing-scripts).

Yet another issue is that when a page is built using JavaScript there's no universal signal you can use to know that the page is "done" being built. You need to decide what event is relevant to you. e.g. I consider the page built when the "Login" button is shown. The you have to wait for that event. I'm using the term "event" loosely here. There may be an actual DOM event that corresponds to what you want or not. (Do note, however that the DOM `load` event does not wait for JavaScript code to do its work. It is emitted as soon as the page's HTML has been processed and *before* any asynchronous JavaScript that may further modify the page.)